# Adapter getView() method getting called when I set the adapter of my GridView in one my place but not when I set it in another

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-gridview, android-adapter, expandablelistadapter

Basically I have 2 Views that both use an Adapter to populate.

1. An ExpandableListView. `ExpandableListView gridHostList;`
2. A custom View that works very similarly to GridView (it's called [StaggeredGridView](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid)) `StaggeredGridView grid;`

Their Adapters in order:

1. `HostListAdapter` which inherits from `BaseExpandableListAdapter`.
2. `GridAdapter` which inherits from `BaseAdapter`.

The reason for this is I need an expandable list with varying numbers of parents or groups where each group contains a grid that also has a varying number of children. I looked into many ways of achieving this and I think this is the best but I am open to alternatives.

In the `getChildView()` method of `HostListAdapter` I make my grid and this works fine.

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_containing_grid, null);
    StaggeredGridView gridView = (StaggeredGridView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
}
```

Now when I set the adapter of my `StaggeredGridView` here as shown below everything works as expected.

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_containing_grid, null);
    StaggeredGridView gridView = (StaggeredGridView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    gridView.setAdapter(mGridAdapter);
}
```

That works fine. However I want to set the adapter from the `Fragment` which contains all of this (it's in a `ViewPager`). To do this I store the view returned by the `hostListAdapter` in a Hashmap with the Hashmap key being a Class I made that contains an ArrayList.

```
gridHostList = (GridHostList) V.findViewById(R.id.gridHostList);

if (!gridsHashMap.containsKey(dataForThisGrid)) {
    gridsHashMap.put(dataForThisGrid, getGrid(0, gridsHashMap.get(dataForThisGrid)));

    StaggeredGridView gridView = (StaggeredGridView) gridsHashMap.get(dataForThisGrid).findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    if (gridView.getAdapter() == null) {
        gridView.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(context);
    }

    private View getGrid(int groupPosition, View convertView) {
        View v;
        v = gridHostList.getExpandableListAdapter().getChildView(groupPosition, 0, true, convertView, gridHostList);
        return v;
    }
}
```

I've tried this without any of the fancy HashMap stuff or logic of any kind to check if that was the problem and found nothing. I know I am actually getting a View from the parent adapter. `gridAdapter.getCount()` is being called by the system and returning a positive int as it should. However the problem seems to come because for some reason `gridAdapter.getView` is never called.

So what I am trying to figure out is why `gridAdapter.getView` is called when I set it in the `hostListAdapter`, but not when I set it in the Fragment which contains this all.

Please forgive minor errors in the code here, I made many changes in the StackOverflow editor (mostly removing logs and changing names for clarity). Thanks for your time.

Comment: When you set the adapter in the fragment is the grid generated properly? I see that the group position is always passed as 0. Also you are checking if condition as gridsHashMap.contains(dataForThisGrid). if this is false then you wont get any data in gridsHashMap.get(dataForThisGrid), which is being passed to getGrid method.

Comment: I'm always passing 0 for group position because I only have 1 group right now for testing purposes. I also checked the Hasmap logic and everything seems to be working fine, but just encase I tried it without the Hasmap (just hardcoded it) and I had the same problem. I seem to be getting the Gridview correctly, I am logging it and calling functions on it without problems.

Comment: If that's the case then it leaves the getAdapter()==null condition. Can you verify if the flow is going inside it?

Comment: The first time it runs it's null, every time after it isn't, which is the intended behavior. But that's not because the child position is 0. I just have it set to 0 because I only want to set an Adapter for 1 child of every group in the ExpandableListAdapter.

Comment: I think somehow I am not getting a reference to the gridView that is actually infalted here: v = gridHostList.getExpandableListAdapter().getChildView(groupPosition, 0, true, convertView, gridHostList);
        return v; But I cannot figure out why.

Comment: I get it 0 is not the issue here. And you might be right about not getting a reference.

Answer (score 0):

In your `getGrid` method you are getting the `StaggeredGridView` and you are adding it to the `gridsHashMap` with the key `dataForThisGrid` . But when you are retrieving it from the `gridsHashMap` you are doing it as `(StaggeredGridView) gridsHashMap.get(dataForThisGrid).findViewById(R.id.grid_view);`.

I think you have to retrieve it using just

`(StaggeredGridView) gridsHashMap.get(dataForThisGrid);`

Note: I have seen people advising not to call the getView or getChildView method directly as calling them will result in inflating the respective view.